# Ipad webview native code interaction

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, webview

I am designing an app which has a number of native widgets and some widgets in webviews.  Now i need to unify the event handling for the web based widgets and the native widgets.  So i need to get back the events from the webview based widgets to the native code.  Is this possible?

An example: a button is present in the webview.  When this button is pressed I need to call a method in the native code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: what you do is you have the HTML buttons point to special URLs that you intercept in the web view delegate's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.  A good way to construct these URLs is to use a special URL scheme, e.g. `x-myapp://do-foo/params`.